# ¿Se puede poner mas de un datalist en un formulario?

Tags: html, html5, datalist

Tengo una duda, se puede poner dos datalist en un mismo formulario y en dos inputs diferentes?
Estuve intentando de varias formas pero en el formulario solo me aparece uno. Y tampoco me tira error, ¿hay alguna otra forma de poner dos datalist?

Por ejemplo: Intente con esto

```
<label for="apiso">Ingrese piso</label>
<input list="piso" name="apiso" class="form-control">

  <datalist id="piso">
    <option value="Planta Baja">
    <option value="Piso 1">
    <option value="Piso 2">
    <option value="Piso 3">          
 </datalist>
```

y otro input

```
<label for="alocal">Ingrese local</label>
  <input list="local" name="alocal" class="form-control">
          <datalist id="local">
          <option value="Comercial">
    <option value="Marketing">
    
    </datalist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí, si que hay una forma de hacerlo, simplemente tienes que meter los `datalist` dentro de la etiqueta `form` y te aparecerán ambos con las opciones que quieras que el usuario pueda seleccionar:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

  <h1>Formulario</h1>

    <form action="/action_page.php" method="get">

      <label for="apiso">Ingrese piso</label>
      <input list="piso" name="apiso" class="form-control">

      <datalist id="piso">
        <option value="Planta Baja">
        <option value="Piso 1">
        <option value="Piso 2">
        <option value="Piso 3">          
      </datalist>

      <br><br>

      <label for="alocal">Ingrese local</label>
      <input list="local" name="alocal" class="form-control">
      
      <datalist id="local">
        <option value="Comercial">
        <option value="Marketing">
      </datalist>

    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!

Comment: A ti! Un saludo

Comment: No me estaba dejando por que tenia el id repetido y por eso no lo podia lograr, pero ahora veo que es muy importante el id y el name! Muchisimas gracias.

Comment: @Dakas Bueno saberlo! Sii son importantísimos, sobre todo el id (debería ser único para identificar de forma unívoca al elemento), de nada!!!